# Overriding - how to do it with less typing?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

Suppose I have

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void Muhahahaha(int a, float f, Object C, Smth else, Etc etc);
};
```

and

```
class B: public A
{
public:
   virtual void Muhahahaha(int a, float f, Object C, Smth else, Etc etc) override;
};
```

Now, what bothers me is the fact that I have to retype the whole argument list every time I override a base-class member function. Why could not I just write something like this:

```
virtual void Muhahahaha override;
```

and the compiler just knows what I want there? Well, excluding the case when there is only one Muhahahaha in there, of course...

Is there such a way?

Comment: `Is there such a way?` No there is not.

Comment: Use a macro (don't shoot...)  ;=)

Comment: The simplest way to do less typing would be to omit `virtual` in the derived class.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess I will have to do some vimscript magic then :) Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there such a way?

Yes, but you must never, ever do it.

> I won't

Look if I show you this, and you do it, my reputation will suffer...

> I *promise*

They'll downvote me just for showing you...

> Go on, please...?

ok then:

```
#define OBFUSCATE Muhahahaha(int a, float f, double C, char etc)

class A
{
public:
    virtual void OBFUSCATE;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual void OBFUSCATE override;
};

void A::OBFUSCATE
{
    // try to debug this
}

void B::OBFUSCATE
{
    // try to debug this too!
}
```

Comment: I won't, I promise :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are taking too many parameters in a single function. This is bad for every function, virtual or not.

As an example for a solution which often works to mitigate this problem, why not bundle `int a, float f, Object C, Smth else, Etc etc` into a class? Like this:

```
struct Parameters
{
    int a;
    float f;
    Object C;
    Smth Else;
    Etc etc;
};
```

Then you have less typing to do:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void Muhahahaha(Parameters const& arguments);
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   void Muhahahaha(Parameters const& arguments) override;
};
```

The fact that you *"have to retype the whole argument list every time"* is just a symptom. Once you refactor your code such that the argument list becomes short, the problem disappears all by itself.